# CoroutineScope.launch doesn't work in TestScope

Tags: android, kotlin, testing, kotlin-coroutines

I have a function that collects a flow and does other operations through launching other coroutines, in my tests for that function it looks like none of my coroutines launches.
is there something I am missing here?

```
class Tax(
    private val coroutineScope: CoroutineScope,
) {
    fun operate() {
        coroutineScope.launch {
            // some work done here 
        }
    }
}

// My Test class 
@Test
fun `test operate`() = runTest {
    val tax = Tax(this)
    tax.operate()
    // verify something with in the coroutineScope.launch always fails
}
```

Comment: Most probably "verify" happens before "some work". Read about synchronous vs asynchronous code execution.

Comment: it doesn't seem to go into the launch block when I debug run

Comment: Please add `delay(100)` after `tax.operate()` - for testing purposes.

Comment: Would be better if you could add an example of how you're verifying the work done within the `launch`.

Comment: @AbdelrhmanTalat did you manage to find an answer to this?

Comment: @AbdelrhmanTalat so did you get a solution for this? And any insights into why it wasn't working in the first place? I've got a similar issue as well.

Comment: @AbdelrhmanTalat Bro, any chance that this is now working for you, facing similar issues, spend hours and no clue.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to instantiate your coroutineScope on a class level and use it to scope your tests and inject into the your `Tax` class, like this:

```
class Tax(
    private val coroutineScope: CoroutineScope,
) {
    fun operate() {
        coroutineScope.launch {
            // some work done here 
        }
    }
}
class YourTestClass {
    private val coroutineScope = TestScope()

    // My Test class 
    @Test
    fun `test operate`() = coroutineScope.runTest {
       val tax = Tax(coroutineScope)
       
       tax.operate()
       // verify something with in the coroutineScope.launch always fails
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You either need to wait till testScheduler schedules coroutine by calling `advanceUntilIdle`, calling coroutineScope or use UnconfinedTestDispatcher as coroutineContext with new TestScope as

```
class SampleTest {
    private val coroutineScope = TestScope()

    // My Test class 
    @Test
    fun `test operate`() = coroutineScope.runTest {
       val tax = Tax(coroutineScope)
       
       tax.operate()
       advanceUntilIdle()

       // verify something with in the coroutineScope.launch always fails
    }

}
```

or use UnconfinedTestDispatcher as

```
class SampleTest {
    private val coroutineScope = TestScope(UnconfinedTestDispatcher())

    // My Test class 
    @Test
    fun `test operate`() = coroutineScope.runTest {
        val tax = Tax(coroutineScope)

        tax.operate()
        advanceUntilIdle()

        // verify something with in the coroutineScope.launch always fails
    }
}
```

You can check out these samples i did based Android Coroutine Test document

```
class UserRepository {
    private val users = mutableListOf<String>()

    fun registerUsers(user: String) {
        users.add(user)
    }

    suspend fun registerUserAsync(user: String) {
        delay(100)
        users.add(user)
    }

    fun getAllUsers(): MutableList<String> {
        return users
    }
}
```

And tests

join

```
@Test
fun standardTestWithJoin() = runTest {
    val userRepo = UserRepository()

    val job1 = launch { userRepo.registerUsers("Alice") }
    val job2 = launch { userRepo.registerUsers("Bob") }

    job1.join()
    job2.join()
    assertEquals(listOf("Alice", "Bob"), userRepo.getAllUsers()) // ✅ Passes
}
```

advanceTillIdle

```
 //  This test passes with registerUserAsync too
    @Test
    fun standardTest2() = runTest {
        val userRepo = UserRepository()

        launch { userRepo.registerUsers("Alice") }
        launch { userRepo.registerUsers("Bob") }
        advanceUntilIdle() // Yields to perform the registrations

        assertEquals(listOf("Alice", "Bob"), userRepo.getAllUsers()) // ✅ Passes
    }
```

UnconfinedTestDispatcher

```
//  This test fails with registerUserAsync(delay)
@Test
fun unconfinedTest() = runTest(UnconfinedTestDispatcher()) {
    val userRepo = UserRepository()

    launch { userRepo.registerUsers("Alice") }
    launch { userRepo.registerUsers("Bob") }

    assertEquals(listOf("Alice", "Bob"), userRepo.getAllUsers()) // ✅ Passes
}

@Test
fun unconfinedTest2() = runTest(UnconfinedTestDispatcher()) {
    val userRepo = UserRepository()

    launch { userRepo.registerUserAsync("Alice") }
    launch { userRepo.registerUserAsync("Bob") }
    //  Need to call for past to test
    advanceUntilIdle()

    assertEquals(listOf("Alice", "Bob"), userRepo.getAllUsers()) // ✅ Passes
}
```

https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines/test#standardtestdispatcher